# How to rename columns of R dataframe based on some existing pattern?

Tags: r, rename, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns with longish names. I want to rename the columns so that they are more easier to work with later on and want to group them into categories.

So, if the column names are like `Subject1.ABCD123.Type1, Subject2ABCD123.Type1, ABCSubject1.ABCD123.Type2, XYZ.Subject3ABCD123.Type2` etc.

I want to change them into something like `Subject1_Type1, Subject2_Type1, Subject1_Type2, Subject3_Type2 etc.`

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
colnames(yourdf) <- sub(".*(Subject\\d+).*(Type\\d+).*", "\\1_\\2", colnames(yourdf))
```

Here, you have 2 patterns that are interesting to you: the one beginning by "Subject" followed by a number, and the one beginning by "Type" and followed by a number. Each of them are put in between brackets in the `regex` expression (parameter `pattern` of function `sub`) so we can retrieve them (with `\\1` and `\\2`) and use them in the parameter `replacement` to have the name we want.

*Example:*

```
sub(".*(Subject\\d+).*(Type\\d+).*", "\\1_\\2", c("Subject1.ABCD123.Type1", "Subject2ABCD123.Type1", "ABCSubject1.ABCD123.Type2", "XYZ.Subject3ABCD123.Type2"))
#[1] "Subject1_Type1" "Subject2_Type1" "Subject1_Type2" "Subject3_Type2"
```